# MySQL MATCH AGAINST and $wpdb->prepare()

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can they work together? I cant find one example anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it with:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
                       WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ("test")');
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

And it works fine. But of course, I had to create a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) on the `post_content` field first, as Wordpress doesn't include this type of index (v3.1).